# How do set a SCSS variable to an empty string?

Tags: sass

I saw an interesting technique where you could use `&` to add a prefix to styles. So the problem I'm running into is making it an option not to set the prefix. No matter what I try I get `Error: Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'` from the sass compiler. So is there any way to add prefixing option but not make it required?

```
$prefix:"";
.#{$prefix}{
  &color{
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use inline condition for `&` sign. Like this:

```
$n: if($prefix != '', '&', '');

#{$n}color {
  color: red;
}
#{$n}left {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: It's more verbose, but it works. I did have to explicitly return the variable the `&` caused an error still. Also, you need to the `.` for classes.

Comment: I have edited the code. So its less verbose now `$n: if($prefix != '', '&', '');`

Comment: The `&` doesn't work. It doesn't return anything. Also, you need the `.` for class declarations.

Comment: The part that I was saying is mroe verbose is the `#{$n}`

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what do you mean by `&` dosen't work.

Comment: Without prefix http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ae8b300ab09fa878e5753f355d4bdc0a, with prefix http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e1ebde3e90985f7380a7c2fbbc18a7eb

Comment: Ok if you add the outer `#{$prefix}` it works, but I removed it because it seemed unnecessary with the new variable declaration. Thanks for the help.